# How can I run jQuery code in AngularJS?

Tags: jquery, angularjs

I have this AngularJS code:

```
                promise.then(function(data) {   
                    $scope.data = data;
                    $scope.hasData = (data.length > 0);

                    // Do jQuery code here
                },
```

As you can see, a promise has been fulfilled (some API data has finished downloading). Only once this data finishes downloading, I want to run some jQuery (I want the page to automatically start scrolling to the bottom over say 60 seconds).

How can I nicely do this? I understand it's not good practice to include jQuery code in the middle of AngularJS code (maybe something about the dollar signs being used by both?) but I'm not sure how to get around it.

Any advice appreciated, thank you.

EDIT:

This is the jQuery code I'll use:

```
        // Scroll up, then scroll down
        var intervalTime = 60000;
        $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop : 0}, 800);
        $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: $('html, body').get(0).scrollHeight }, { duration: (0.75 * intervalTime) });
```

Comment: You can use angular.element:
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element.
This is a wrapper to jQuery, so I don't think it's a bad practice to put jQuery animations code inside AngularJS

Comment: Do you have an example of angular.element being used? That documentation page is light on the examples! Cheers. I've edited the top post with my jQuery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the [ngAnimate](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngAnimate) module:

In your view:

```xml
<div ng-class="{scrollToBottom: promiseExecuted}">...</div>
```

In your controller:

```js
promise.then(function(data) {   
    $scope.data = data;
    $scope.hasData = data.length > 0;
    $scope.promiseExecuted = true;
});
```

Then your animation:

```js
app.animation(".scrollToBottom", function() {
    var intervalTime = 60000;
    return {
        addClass: function(element, className, done) {
            $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop : 0 }, 800);
            $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: $("html, body").get(0).scrollHeight }, { duration: (0.75 * intervalTime) });
        }
    };
});
```

Comment: Ah this looks so elegant - but it's not working! Does it matter that I have my code like this `angular.module('application', [])
.animation('.scrollToBottom', function() { ...` instead of having it as a `var app = ....`? And does the order matter? ie. Can "animation" be the first function, or does "controller", etc need to come first? Thanks

Comment: @b85411 I guess you forgot to load the module, see the "Installation" section at the end of the [ngAnimate module documation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngAnimate). Chaining does not matter, nor the declaration order (AFAIK).

Comment: Thank you! Good pick up, I hadn't loaded the `ngAnimate` module. You deserve a million up-votes, because I have not been able to find anything on StackOverflow as concise and elegant as the solution you put above.